# Is there any function in Android to add PDF files?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf

I am making an Android app which will contain several PDF files, so that when I share this application with my friends they must be able to download these PDF files. But I am unaware of how to add PDF files in Android applications. Is there any function to do so?

Comment: If the apk contains the files then what do you have in mind with downloading?

Comment: In the IDE add the files manually to the assets directory of your project.

Comment: Like , I build an apk of my project and share with others , will they be able to download PDF ?

Comment: Download from where to where?

Answer (score 0):

Webview would be the easiest form of PDF viewing. Maybe start from there and work yourself up to something more demanding.

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf file.